# "The crying baby gets the milk"

Tags: etymology, popular-refrains

Where does the saying "The crying baby gets the milk" come from? I don't think it's from English.

Comment: In Spanish we say "el que no llora, no mama", which is almost a literal translation of "the crying baby gets the milk".

Comment: @Gus That's stretching the meaning of "literal" quite a lot.

Comment: @Reg ... hence "almost", perhaps? I believe the point Gus was making is valid; while the phrase is not a word for word direct translation, the underlying meaning is obviously extremely similar.

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh Literal has a literal meaning.  “He who does not cry, does not nurse” ***is*** the literal translation.  That’s quite different from the title of this posting.

Comment: @Reg I think we can agree that the phrase is not a literal translation. I am of the opinion however that it might be considered an "almost literal" translation, given that the *underlying* meaning is the same, even if the *superficial construction* is different. I humbly suggest that you may be being a tad overcritical in this case, though I admit I may be being a tad lenient. Anyway, we should probably let it drop....

Comment: Chinese always say "会哭的孩子有奶吃" which is identical translation.

Comment: I am pretty sure it comes from the Chinese saying as brought up by @est

Answer (score 8):

The English equivalent would be, "the squeaky wheel gets the grease."
I don't recognize the milk idiom though.

Comment: "The crying baby gets the milk" does seem to have English roots and relatively common usage; perhaps more in B.E. than A.E.

Comment: Not to this B.E. speaker. Never heard it before.

Comment: @Colin. This native B.E. speaker has heard neither the 'crying baby' idiom nor the 'squeaky wheel' idiom previously.